# VBA Names - Where are they referenced?

Tags: vba, excel

I have defined a large number of named cells on one worksheet of a workbook. Each name may be used multiple times (or never) on that worksheet or others in the workbook. Is there a way to get a list of the where else in the workbook the names are used?

For example, lets say I define the name `Fred` for a cell on `Sheet1`. There is an equation on sheet2, cell B6 that is `=Fred*6`. How do I get a function to return `Sheet2!B6` and any other places that `Fred` is used?

I hope this is clear enough. :)

Comment: I'd set a loop through all formula cells in all worksheets and do an instr to find the name. What do you think?

Comment: @nutsch, alternatively you could use loop + `Range.Find property` to do the thing.

Comment: You can also use the Trace Dependents list.

Comment: @nutsch, [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197707(v=office.15).aspx): `The Dependents property only works on the active sheet and can not trace remote references`

Answer (score 5):

The free version of JKP and my Name Manager Addin can show you where a particular name is used.
 You can download this addin from http://www.decisionmodels.com/downloads.htm

 When I wrote the FastExcel extended version of Name Manager I added a Name Map facility that shows you a count of where the names are used (or not) by Worksheet and Other Names.
 This is done by parsing out the Names from all the formulas on all the worksheets and the formulas in the Names Refers-tos (recursively), using a special-purpose parser and evaluating cases like the use of INDIRECT.